# how to send email with attached file in android?

Tags: android

The email is sent successfully,but problem is attaching file with email,how i send an email.I am using below code.

```
public class SendMail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    private String _user;
    private String _pass;

    private String[] _to;
    private String _from;

    private String _port;
    private String _sport;

    private String _host;

    private String _subject;
    private String _body;

    private boolean _auth;

    private boolean _debuggable;

    private Multipart _multipart;

    public SendMail() {
        _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server 
        _port = "465"; // default smtp port 
        _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port 

        _user = ""; // username 
        _pass = ""; // password 
        _from = ""; // email sent from 
        _subject = ""; // email subject 
        _body = ""; // email body 

        _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
        _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

        _multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
        MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
        mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
        mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
        mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
        mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
        mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
        CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
    }

    public SendMail(String user, String pass) {
        this();

        _user = user;
        _pass = pass;
    }

    public boolean send() throws Exception {
        Properties props = _setProperties();

        if (!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);

            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));

            List<String> addressTo = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String addr : _to) {
                if (addr == null || addr.trim().equals(""))
                    continue;
                addressTo.add(addr);
            }

            InternetAddress[] actAddressTo = new InternetAddress[addressTo.size()];
            int i = 0;
            for (String addr : addressTo) {
                actAddressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(addr);
                i++;
            }

            msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, actAddressTo);

            msg.setSubject(_subject);
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());

            // setup message body 
            //BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            //messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
            //_multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            //msg.setContent(_multipart, "text/html");
            msg.setContent(_body, "text/html");

            // send email 
            Transport.send(msg);

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }

    @Override
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass);
    }

    private Properties _setProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);

        if (_debuggable) {
            props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        }

        if (_auth) {
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        }

        props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        return props;
    }

    // the getters and setters 
    public String getBody() {
        return _body;
    }

    public void setBody(String _body) {
        this._body = _body;
    }

    public void setTo(String[] _to) {
        this._to = _to;
    }

    public void setFrom(String _from) {
        this._from = _from;
    }

    public void setSubject(String _subject) {
        this._subject = _subject;
    }

}
```

Please help me?

Answer (score 4):

```
String[] mailto = {""};
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/CALC/REPORTS/",pdfname ));
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, mailto);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Calc PDF Report");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, ViewAllAccountFragment.selectac+" PDF Report");
emailIntent.setType("application/pdf");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email using:"));
```

Comment: Avoid giving "code-only" answers. You can add an explanation as to how/why it could work with regards the question.

Answer (score 2):

First I think you lack of a clear example on this topic; So [here](http://mooriandroid.blogspot.in/p/email-attachment-from.html) it is;

As far as the coding goes, you concentrate on the following part:

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(

android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

emailIntent.setType("application/octet-stream");

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,

new String[] { address.getText().toString() });

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,

subject.getText());

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,

emailtext.getText());

emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(attachment));

EmailActivity.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,

"Send mail..."));
```

The setType is sooo important here, concentrate on it and you could get it right in no time

Answer (score 1):

you can attach image in action_send so try this...

```
sPhotoFileName=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/sankettest/siteriskassesment.png";



    send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
            emailIntent.setType("image/*");

            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] 
            {"me@gmail.com"}); 
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, 
            "Test Subject"); 
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
            "go on read the emails"); 
            Log.v(getClass().getSimpleName(), "sPhotoUri=" + Uri.parse("file:///"+ sPhotoFileName));
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/sanket test/siteriskassesment.png"));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Method for the email the pdf attachment
    public void EmailPDF()
    {
        File PayslipDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/FolderName/");
        // Write your file to that directory and capture the Uri
        String strFilename = "PDFFile.pdf";
        File htmlFile = new File(PayslipDir, strFilename);
        // Save file encoded as html
        Uri htmlUri = Uri.fromFile(htmlFile);
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("application/pdf");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] {TOEmailAddress});
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Pdf attachment");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Hi PDF is attached in this mail. ");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, htmlUri);
        CurrentActivityName.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,"Send mail..."));
        //finish(); 
    }
```

This are the three lines to attach any type of file

```
Uri htmlUri = Uri.fromFile(htmlFile);
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("application/pdf");
```

Comment: @veeresh  Is this answer is helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to sent a mail

```
String filelocation="/mnt/sdcard/contacts_sid.vcf";    
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
String to[] = "asd@gmail.com";
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,filelocation);
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"subject");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Send email"));
```