# how to attach single file in email in android?

Tags: android, email, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to send email with attached file in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244782/how-to-send-email-with-attached-file-in-android)

When I send email than shows file attachment 0 byte in inbox. My code is below. how to solve this problem? in advance thank you.

```
             String path = "/data/data/"
               + context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
               + "/files/";
             String filename= "save.ime";
             Intent mSendIntent = new Intent(
                android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        mSendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mSendIntent.setType("plain/text");
        mSendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                new String[] { "" });
        mSendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, "");
        mSendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC, "");
        mSendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                "InfoMe Profile Request");
        mSendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new 
               File(path+filename)));
        mSendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                Function.bodypart);
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(
                mSendIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244782/how-to-send-email-with-attached-file-in-android/13244852#13244852

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
filesend = new File("/data/data/"
           + context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
           + "/files/");
File filelocation = filesend ;
Intent mSendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
mSendIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
mSendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "user@gmail.com" );
mSendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+filelocation.getAbsolutePath()));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mSendIntent, "Send email"));
```

Comment: but my file is not jpeg it is make using serializable object.and also shows zero byte in email inbox

Comment: no that is not image. that is only serializable object file.

Comment: just check it once with my code replace image/jpeg with text/plain and instead of user your mail id

Comment: i have little work come back afternoon

Comment: no sir that is not work.

Comment: hey it is work perfectly thanks. actually i changed my file path.and work perfect.thanks