# Not able to send .csv file with email in android

Tags: android, csv, mime-types

I am going to attach ".csv" in mail and send it. but facing the problem that the csv file is not available at receiver side.

I have tried too many Mime types

**application/octet-stream, text/comma-separated-values, text/csv, application/csv, application/excel, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.msexcel**

but the file is not attached with the mail.

below are the code which i have used to send the mail

```
public boolean sendEmail() {
    boolean success = false;
    Intent intentSendMail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    File mydir = getApplicationContext().getDir(Global.FOLDERNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
    File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, Global.FILENAME); 
    if (!fileWithinMyDir.exists() || !fileWithinMyDir.canRead()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Attachment Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        success = false;
    } else {
        intentSendMail.setType("text/csv");

        intentSendMail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(fileWithinMyDir));

        intentSendMail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                "Subject");

        intentSendMail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Sent from my phone.");

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentSendMail, "E-mail"));

        success = true;
    }
    return success;
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you get any error ?

Comment: Try moving the file to the SD Card and attaching it from there

Comment: @GrIsHu There is no error. I am able to send the mail. but file is not attached...

Comment: Where is your file located ?

Comment: It's in application memory...

Comment: @RaghavSood i have move the file into external file storage. but still facing same problem

Comment: Hi. I solve out this problem.
1. Move the file to external storage.
2. Then just append "file://" before uri string. So, it will worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for this problem.
Below are the solution

```
public boolean sendEmail() {
    String destLocation = "";
    String FILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"";
    destLocation =  FILE + "/" + Global.FILENAME;


    boolean success = false;
    Intent intentSendMail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    File mydir = getApplicationContext().getDir(Global.FOLDERNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
    File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, Global.FILENAME);

    copyFile(Uri.fromFile(fileWithinMyDir).toString(),destLocation);

    if (!fileWithinMyDir.exists() || !fileWithinMyDir.canRead()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Attachment Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        success = false;
    } else {
        intentSendMail.setType("application/csv");
        intentSendMail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+destLocation));

        intentSendMail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                "Test Play file.");
        intentSendMail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentSendMail, "E-mail"));

        success = true;
    }
    return success;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try out as below:

> ```
> String FILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator
>         + "Foldername";
>    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
>    sendIntent.setType("application/csv");
>    sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "");
>    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
>    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
>    String temp_path = FILE + "/" + "Filename.csv";
>    File F = new File(temp_path);
>     Uri U = Uri.fromFile(F);
>     sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, U);
>     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send Mail"));
> ```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Sorry, still i am not able to receive attached csv file.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/sanket test/siteriskassesment.csv"));
```

OR

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13244824/942224)

Comment: Sorry, still i am not able to receive attached csv file.

Comment: have you try to parse Uri insted of from file?

Comment: i have pass the uri in the intent. file displayed as attahced in device but not received at receiver end.